# Pymatgen XRD Plot

Tags: pymatgen

I am following the XRD plot  tutorial and as it told in this tutorial I imported

```
from pymatgen import Lattice, Structure
from pymatgen.analysis.diffraction.xrd import XRDCalculator
from IPython.display import Image, display
%matplotlib inline
```

And after defining the structure I try to plot it with these commands

```
c = XRDCalculator()
c.show_xrd_plot(structure)
```

But I bump into this error: *'no attribute 'show_xrd_plot'*

```
AttributeError: 'XRDCalculator' object has no attribute 'show_xrd_plot'
```

What should I do to make it work, many thanks in advance,
Happy Thanksgiving

Answer (score 1):

The [XRD tutorial of pymatgen](http://matgenb.materialsvirtuallab.org/2013/01/01/Calculating-XRD-patterns.html) is updated and xrd_show_plot it changed to

```
c.show_plot(structure)
```